# Photo application

Tags: c#, image, image-manipulation

I'm developing an application just for fun that consists of capturing images from a webcam.

What I would like to know is how can I apply some filters to the image that I capture? Ideally I would like to develop something like Apple iPhoto; something that defaces the image.

The programming language I am using is C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wnat to implement the filter algorithms, first of all you have to find all operations involved in the algorithm (also a simple low-pass can involve a bit of work) and then you need to access every single pixels of the image (you can do this using Image or Bitmap classes, using the Set/GetPixel method.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to do some interesting coding to achieve this.  My suggestion is to do some research.  Image manipulation, such as converting formats, resizing, cropping, zooming, is simple enough.  You could even just write a front-end for an existing image manipulation tool, such as this one:  http://kfoo.net/products/imgman/

If your looking to do image "warping" or other advanced manipulation, you are in for some fun.

Comment: In the intervening ~3 years the referenced link has broken.  Do you know if there is a mirror/copy of the code somewhere else?

Comment: @Peter Creator offered the following link:  http://www.kfoo.net/_download/ImgMan.zip