# Deface images and apply filters

Tags: c#, image-processing, image-manipulation

**Exact duplicate of**

> [Photo application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747860/photo-application)

Hi people.

I'm developing an application, just for fun, that consists of capturing the image from a webcam.

What I would like to know is: How can I apply some filters to the image that make things like iPhoto programm from Apple. Things like defacements, etc.

I'm using C# as programming language.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for a suitable library.

There is one at :
[codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Image_Processing_Lab.aspx)

I don not know if this suits you.
There should be others out there.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would look at would be whether you can do what you are after with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) - a fairly complete open-source library for image processing that has APIs available for most languages.